# Sources on Jacobi Elliptic Functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, elliptic-functions

I'm interested in learning more about the Jacobi Elliptic Functions and the associated theta functions. For instance, what was the initial motivation for defining them? What are some applications? Is there a good book on this subject I can look at?

Comment: Have you checked the references on the Wikipedia page? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions